# Does Facebook token's dataAccessExpirationDate is refreshed automatically by the SDK?

Tags: facebook

According to Facebook, the access token doesn't expire if the user keeps visiting the app, because the "SDKs automatically refresh the token" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data#testing-when-access-to-user-data-expires)

But I still don't understand if it also refreshes the dataAccessExpirationDate?

Thanks

Comment: _“The expiration period for data access is 90 days, based on when the user was last active.”_ - they don’t specify explicitly what “active” means there, but I would assume it means that the app makes any kind of API call with the user token

Answer (score 0):

So I reached out to Facebook and the answer is no:

"Data access is valid for 90 days from the time the user grants the permissions via the login or reauthorisation dialog. Refreshing an access token doesn't extend the data access expiry date."

From https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/710438336507883/